# PHP Switch Case Url's

Tags: php, case, switch-statement

We currently use Switch case url config to help us with the navigation on some of our urls, Im not sure if there is an easier way to do it but i couldnt seem to find 1.

```
<?php if (! isset($_GET['step']))
    {
        include('./step1.php');

    } else {    
        $page = $_GET['step'];  
        switch($page)
        {
            case '1':
                include('./step1.php');
                break;  
            case '2':
                include('./step2.php');
                break; 
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Now this system works perfectly but the only snag we hit is if they type in xxxxxx.php?step=3 boom they just get a blank page and that should be correct as there is no case for it to handle '3' but what i was wondering is .. is there any php code i could add to the bottom that may tell it for any case other than those 2 to redirect it back to xxxxx.php ?

Thanks

Daniel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `default` case. That is, change your switch to something like this:

```
<?php if (! isset($_GET['step']))
    {
        include('./step1.php');

    } else {    
        $page = $_GET['step'];  
        switch($page)
        {
            case '1':
                include('./step1.php');
                break;  
            case '2':
                include('./step2.php');
                break; 
            default:
                // Default action
            break;
        }
    }
?>
```

The default case will be executed for every case which is not explicitly specified.

Answer (score 2):

All `switch` statements allow a `default` case that will fire if no other case does. Something like...

```
switch ($foo)
{
  case 1:
    break;
  ...
  default:
    header("Location: someOtherUrl");
}
```

would work. You may, however, want to Google around for other, more robust and extensible, page dispatch solutions.

Answer (score 1):

How about a different approach with something along the lines of:

```
<?php
$currentStep = $_GET['step'];
$includePage = './step'.$currentStep.'.php'; # Assuming the pages are structured the same, i.e. stepN where N is a number

if(!file_exists($includePage) || !isset($currentStep)){ # If file doesn't exist, then set the default page
    $includePage = 'default.php'; # Should reflect the desired default page for steps not matching 1 or 2
}

include($includePage);
?>
```